# Number of sets in 4 positions

Tags: combinatorics

Let's assume I have 4 positions (let's give letters to those positions: m,n,l,p). Each position can be occupied by numbers from 0 up to N-1 with repetition allowed. For instance, let's assume N=3:

m n l p

0,0,0,0

0,0,0,1

0,0,0,2

0,0,1,0

0,0,1,1

0,0,1,2

0,0,2,0

0,0,2,1

0,0,2,2

0,1,0,0

.  .  .

.  .  .

.  .  .

2,2,2,2

I'd like to find a equation/formula where I can find the number of elements in each one of the following groups:

1)

m=n=l=p

2)

(m=n=l)!=p

(m=n=p)!=l

(m=l=p)!=n

(n=l=p)!=m

3)

(m=n)!=(l=p)

(m=l)!=(n=p)

(m=p)!=(n=l)

4)

(m=n)!=(l!=p)

(m=l)!=(p!=n)

(m=p)!=(l!=n)

(p=n)!=(m!=l)

(p=l)!=(m!=n)

(n=l)!=(p!=m)

5)

m!=n!=l!=p

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than doing the case $N=3$ we shall do $N=n$. When we use different letters in a configuration, they are understood to indicate different values.

The configuration $aaaa$ will occur with mutliplicity $1$ and there are $n$ of these.

The configuration $aaab$ will occur with mutliplicity $4$ and there are $n(n-1)$ of these.

The configuration $aabb$ will occur with mutliplicity $6$ and there are $n(n-1)/2$ of these.

The configuration $aabc$ will occur with mutliplicity $12$ and there are $n(n-1)(n-2)/2$ of these.

The configuration $abcd$ will occur with mutliplicity $24$ and there are $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)/24$ of these.

You will quickly verify that
\begin{eqnarray*}
1 \times n + 4 \times n(n-1) +6 \times \frac{n(n-1)}{2} +12 \times \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{2} \\+ 24 \times \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{24} =n^4
\end{eqnarray*}
as expected.